# a multiple choice question on distance between two sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. For subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$, define
$$d( A , B) = \inf\{d(a, b) : a \in A, b \in B\}$$
Which of the following statements are true?

1. If $\left(\overline {A} \cap \overline B\right) = \phi$, then $d(A, B) \gt 0$
2. If $d(A, B) \gt 0$, then there exist open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $A\subset U$, $B\subset V$ and  $U \cap V =\phi $
3. $d(A, B) = 0$ if and only if there exists a sequence of points {$x_n$} in $A$
   converging to a point in $B$.

Comment: Please show some work, and use standard capitalization, punctuation, spacing, spelling, and grammar.

Answer (score 2):

For part $2$ we prove that the assertion is true.

If $d(A, B) > 0$, then let $e = d(A, B)$, and consider the balls $U = \cup _{x\in A}B(x,e/4)$ and $V = \cup _{y\in B}B(x,e/4)$ then, both $U$ and $V$ are open since they are union of open sets, and they contain $A$ and $B$ respectively.

It remains to show $U\cap V\neq \emptyset$.

If $w\in U\cap V$ then $w\in B(x,e/4)\cap B(y, e/4)$ for some $x\in A,y\in B$ then $d(w,x) < e/4$, and $d(w,y) < e/4$.

So,  $d(x,y) < e/4 + e/4 = e/2$. But $d(x, y) > d(A,B) = e$.

So a contradiction is obtained.

Comment: I really like your explanation so i thought to edit this to make it look better... Please see that i have not changed your idea....

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

Choose $A=\{(x,y) : y=0\}$ and $B=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : xy=1\}$

Remember that $A$ and $B$ are closed.

This should tell you that $(1)$ and $(3)$ are True/False.

Comment: Our metric space isn't $(\mathbb{R}^2, \lVert \cdot \rVert)$ necessarily, so finding an example from just this metric space doesn't necessarily mean it holds for all metric spaces.

Comment: @P yes, I see what you're doing - just figured he might be looking for a more generalized argument

Comment: @P you can look for contradictions in a general sense or in a specific sense, I prefer the general sense, personally.

Comment: @P I didn't mean to offend, I am sorry, was just trying to explain why I said what I said